# HTML code for simple page showing a graphic filling a square

Tags: html

I've never written a webpage and know zippola about HTML code but I'm reading some newbie guides and starting to learn.
My question is how would I make a simple vertical rectangle with say 10 squares stacked together. Then depending on the input those squares would go from white to green depending on a specific input (This input would come from a microcontroller which is another piece of my overall project).

I just need to know what's the html code to do something like the picture I'm attaching. The microcontroller I'll be using 10 GPIO's as simple True/False input so when 1 GPIO = TRUE I want that corresponding square to turn green.

I haven't tried anything since I honestly have no idea where to start.  Not looking for anything fancy literally just a blank webpage that has the vertically stacked squares (so they all look connected)

[image]

Comment: It would be easy to answer your question as asked, giving you HTML (with embedded CSS) for colored squares, but your overall project is missing a vital component: How are the GPIOs connected to your PC, and how are the values arriving in software? The HTML to use is likely depending a lot on the answer to that question.

Comment: Thanks Martin, yeah I didn't give a full picture of what I'm doing. I was thinking of figuring out my project in pieces. The HTML code being one. In anycase I'm using a raspberry pico W connecting to my network using wireless connection. The PICO W is going to be hosting the webpage. I'm using adafruit.com and their guide how to set up an http server. 
I know there's also going to be a bit of micropython magic I need to work on to be able to then "change" the html code depending on the GPIO input values but I figured that would be my next "piece" to work on once I figured out the HTML part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer for the question about HTML. It contains embedded CSS for the size and color of the squares, but uses separate CSS rules (as opposed to inline styles at the DIVs) to make the styles easier to change. This answer does not deal with how the GPIOs are connected to the computer or how the values arrive in software -- depending on that, you might need code that generates the HTML, or javascript code in the HTML that reads the signals from the GPIOs, or a different solution.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .square0, .square1 {
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
        }
        .square0 {
            background-color: white;
        }
        .square1 {
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="square0"></div>
    <div class="square0"></div>
    <div class="square1"></div>
    <div class="square0"></div>
    <div class="square1"></div>
    <div class="square1"></div>
    <div class="square0"></div>
    <div class="square1"></div>
    <div class="square1"></div>
    <div class="square1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: awesome thanks Martin this is exactly what I was looking for but yes definitely the next piece is I need to figure out how I would use micropython to make the necessary changes to the code. Specifically I would use 10 GPIO's (0 - 9). 0 being the bottom square and up through 9 being the top. If any of those change from False to True I would want my circuitpython script to make a change in the html code. That's the next piece I would wanna figure out. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: It was a bit of a lucky bet, but a script that outputs "parameterized" HTML is most compatible with what I answered, so you can directly use that HTML. For instance, a HTML page that shows live changes in the signals as blinking squares would have required Javascript that reads signals and updates the HTML, and would have looked entirely different.